# Unable to select select dropdown with Selenium Python

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I have the following html:

```
<div class="flex flex-col pt-4 pb-1 border-t border-gray-100 dark:border-gray-600 mt-2" style="display: none;">
<div class="w-full mb-4"><label class="input-label">MyComboBox</label>
<div class="flex flex-row">
<div class="relative flex-1">
<select class="input-block" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
<option value="">FirstOption</option>
<option value="26">SecondOption</option>
<option value="27">ThirdOption</option>
    ...
```

I am trying to select one of the dropdown options using Selenium with Python. But no matter what I do, I get `ElementNotInteractableException`.

Things I have double-checked:

- The element is fully visible, not being hidden by anything
- The element should be fully loaded when the code is run (I have tried clicking myself on the box and it works fine)
- I tried executing click on the dropdown before getting the select options, but it gives me the same `ElementNotInteractableException`
- I have tried to use visibility_of_element_located and element_to_be_clickable, but those are never true for this element
- I have printed `len(select.options)` and it is returning the number of options correctly, so the dropdown options are being found correctly, I am just unable to interact with them in any way (either clicking the dropdown before or clicking the select option)

These is my attempt:

```
        dropdown = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
                                              "//label[contains(text(), 'MyComboBox')]/following-sibling::div//select[@class='input-block']")))

        select = Select(dropdown)
        select.select_by_value("26")
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

For debugging you can use selenium screenshot feature for making sure it see what you want like:

```
driver.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')
```

After that you can check if it is inside a iframe and switch to iframe with:

```
driver.switch_to.frame("iframe-name-or-id")
```

And you can also try with other selectors as:

```
By.CLASS_NAME
By.CSS_SELECTOR
```